# PHP Simple If Statement Failing

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

My if statements are not working despite the log file confirming that the values meet the conditions required.

As you will see below I have attempted to use both boolean and numerical values (as I have read that there are a few quirks with boolean statements in PHP.)

```
  $lift = isset($p["lift"]) ? $p["lift"] : 0;
  $parking = isset($p["parking"]) ? $p["parking"] : false;

// LIFT
  if ( $lift === 1 && $home ) {
    $query .= " AND `lift` == $lift";

  }

  // PARKING
  if ( $parking === 1 && $home ) {
    $query .= " AND `parking` != '';";
  }


  $log_file = "../../queries.log"; 
  $error_message = "query: '$query' \n\n lift: ".$lift."\n home: ".$home."\n";  
  error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);
```

I have tried both double and triple equal operators without success. I have tried both boolean and numerical values. The log statement prints the following:

```
'SELECT id, ref_crm, `type`, prov_name, prov_id, muni_name, muni_id, barrio, price_latest, photo,sqm,bed,bath,lift,parking,`year`,descr,
            x(pt) as lat, y(pt) as lng, ref_cat FROM outlet WHERE prov_id = '06' AND `type` = 'Piso' AND price_latest >= 0 AND price_latest <= 500000 AND sqm >= 0 AND sqm <= 200'

 lift: 1

 home: true
```

As you can see, the string statements are not being attached to the query despite the two conditions both being met.

I have also tried removing the variables I've created (`$lift` and `$home`) and simply used `$p["lift"]` and `$p["parking"]` without success. The only way I am able to make this work is to specifically state `$lift === 1` and `$home === true` (double or triple equal operators) above the conditions. This despite the log confirming that these variables already have those values set! I have also tried double and triple equal operators with `$home` and `$p["home"]`

Comment: Where is the `$home` variable coming from?

Comment: `$home` appears to be undefined. Show us how you create that and what its value is. You will never enter your `if` block unless `$home` is truth-y

Comment: try `(int)$lift === 1`  and `(int)$parking === 1`

Comment: there are two possibilities 1. $home is not define 2.  $lift & $parking is string and you comparing with int (try ==).

Comment: You do not use  a double `=` in sql, just singles so `AND lift = $lift` rather than `AND lift == $lift` etc

Comment: $home = isset($p["home"]) ? $p["home"] : true;

Comment: Solved by Shanteshwar Inde. The problem was that the values were strings. This was not apparent by simply reading the log file

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing something out within your if statements.

Also please note:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Solution:

```
if (!empty($home) && $lift == 1) {
 echo 'Lift works';
} else {
 echo 'Lift is not 1';
}

if (!empty($home) && $parking == 1) {
 echo 'Parking works';
} else {
 echo 'Error: home parking is not 1';
}
```